# Subtracting within a Range for a loop

Tags: excel, vba

Attempting to create a dynamic, looping selection with the intentions of cutting every 3 columns and pasting them into the first 3 columns at the bottom of the data. Newish to VBA and wondering if the following can be done:

```
Sub ColumnCut()
    Dim iCol2 As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim CutRange As Range
        iCol2 = 78
        LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        CutRange = Range(Cells(1, iCol2), Cells(LastRow, iCol2 - 3))
        CutRange.Select  
End Sub
```

So CutRange should contain a selection of the 3 columns I want to cut. Which I'll later code to paste at the bottom of the 3 first columns. The problem I'm having is with this line:

```
CutRange = Range(Cells(1, iCol2), Cells(LastRow, iCol2 - 3))
```

Where I'm attempting to subtract 3 to iCol2 to give me the 3 column range I want. I'm not even sure if something like that is possible, the results don't seem to do anything and make it difficult to troubleshoot. iCol2 will eventually be used in a loop to move all the columns I have.

Comment: You need to `set cutrange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
CutRange = Range(Cells(1, iCol2), Cells(LastRow, iCol2 - 3))
```

to:

```
Set CutRange = Range(Cells(1, iCol2), Cells(LastRow, iCol2 - 3))
```